# Sorting CSV file from longest to shortest based on the first column only

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file like this:

```
cat, animal
dog, animal
bear, animal
elephant, animal
tree, object
```

I want to sort the data, from longest word to shortest word, based on the first column. E.g.:

```
elephant, animal
bear, animal
tree, object
cat, animal
dog, animal
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F',' '{print length($1),$0}' input.csv | sort -k1nr | cut -d' ' -f 2-
elephant, animal
bear, animal
tree, object
cat, animal
dog, animal
```

#### Explanation:

- **`awk`** add one column to record length of csv column#1
- **`sort`** sort by the first column numerically
- **`cut`** remove first column

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{print length($0) ":" $0}' csvfile |
sort -t: -k 1nr -k 2 |
sed 's/^[0-9]*://'
```

Add a length, sort numerically in reverse on the lengths, then alphabetically on the rest of the line, then strip the lengths off again.  On the test data, it gives the required result.

Whether it counts as `bash` is perhaps slightly debatable, though.